# d3 axis ticks not lining up correctly

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js, scale, axis

[image]

I'm having trouble making the % total axis align properly.  Here's the relevant code.

```
var totalPercentageAxisScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(dataTop.percent_of_total)
            .rangeBands([0, width]);

        var totalPercentageAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(totalPercentageAxisScale)
            .tickValues(dataTop.percent_of_total)
            .tickPadding([15]);

        var botTotPercAxisScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(dataBottom.percent_of_total)
            .rangeBands([0, width]);

        var botTotPercAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(botTotPercAxisScale)
            .tickValues(dataBottom.percent_of_total);

        chartWrapper.select(".chart-two").append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0, " + (heightBottom + 12) + ")").attr("class", "axis").call(botTotPercAxis);
        chartWrapper.select(".chart-two").append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0, " + (heightBottom + 24) + ")").attr("class", "axis").call(botPercChangeAxis);
```

console.log(JSON.stringify(dataTop.percent_of_total), JSON.stringify(dataBottom.percent_of_total));
returns...
    ["-0.04%","0.18%","0.41%","0.12%","0.1%","0.01%","0.01%"]    ["-0.1%","0.16%","0.38%","0.16%","0.06%","0.05%","0.01%"]

Comment: I believe d3 is removing values that are duplicates.  in the first dataset there are 2 values of "0.01%" so it removes one.  In the second it removes one of the "0.16%"'s.  I'm pretty sure that's the diagnosis, but I still don't know the cure.

Comment: You're right that it's removing duplicates. See if you can set the scales' domains to be the array of data that you're binding to when rendering the bars, then use the axis's `.tickFormat(function(d) { return ...})` method to extract and return the desired tick value out of `d`. (note: I haven't tried this approach, and there may be something more idiomatic)

Comment: I like the idea but that is the array I'm binding the data to...

Comment: It sounds to me like you wouldn't want to use a scale for this at all, but add the values manually.